# How do I install/downgrade version 7.35.0 of Curl on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, downgrade, curl

Is it possible to install or downgrade curl version 7.35.0 on ubuntu 16.04?

Default curl version is 7.47.0 in ubuntu 16.04 but I want to install curl 7.35.0. If possible please help me ASAP.

Comment: For what exactly do you need cURL 7.35 and why is cURL 7.47 insufficient?

Comment: Version is not match when I try to data transfer form one server to another server. That the issue but I want to know have any restriction to install curl 7.35.0 on ubuntu 16.04 bcz I try in different way but failed again again.  please help.

Every time same error: 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:744: recipe for target 'curl' failed
make[2]: *** [curl] Error 1

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: What data do you want to transfer and through which protocol? The cURL version really shouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

I advise strongly against the replacement of any software component from the repositories by a lower version because it's likely going to break something else that relies on this component with at least this version.

I also doubt that cURL v7.47 cannot somehow perform a task that v7.35 could perform. Maybe the usage changed slightly. It would help if you clarified what you want to achieve with it.

If the installation of cURL v7.35 turns out to be the best option for you after all you can [download](https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.35.0.tar.bz2) and [install it from source](/q/25961/175814). *Take care to not overwrite the cURL installation of Ubuntu!* You can do that if you specify an installation prefix other than `/usr`, e. g.

```
./configure --prefix=~/.local/curl
```

will install the cURL executable at `~/.local/curl/bin/curl`. The default installation prefix is `/usr/local` and will not overwrite the system installation.

Comment: I try as per your instruction but failed, please find the bellow error message...@David Foerster
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:744: recipe for target 'curl' failed
make[2]: *** [curl] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/curl-7.35.0/src'
Makefile:622: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/curl-7.35.0/src'
Makefile:676: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](/posts/896002/edit), when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.